# Maximum call stack size exceeded when using $ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have very simple form with a couple of dropdowns that are filled using data fetched from API calls. Nothing fancy about the API calls they are just for Countries and States.

I then fill out the form and send the JSON data to a WebAPI call.
The Request will be added as a record and the Id returned. That's the GET for.

Here's the JS code:

```
function ExternalModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.Name = $('#txtName').val();
    self.URL = $('#txtURL').val();
    self.PhoneNumber = $('#txtPhoneNumber').val();
    self.ContactPerson = $('#txtContactPerson').val();
    self.EmailAddress = $('#txtEmailAddress').val();
    self.AddressName = $('#txtAddressName').val();
    self.Address = $('#txtAddress').val();
    self.CountryId = $('#selCountryId option:selected').val();
    self.StateId = $('#selStateId option:selected').val();
    self.City = $('#txtcity').val();
    self.ZipCode = $('#txtzip').val();
}

jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajaxSettings.async = false;
    var RequestObject = new ExternalModel();
    var RequestJSON = JSON.stringify(RequestObject);
    $.ajax({
        url: ReqUrl,
        type: "Get",
        data: RequestJSON,
        dataType: "json",
        //crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // If posted  data is valid                
            if (data) {
                DisplayMessage(data);
            }
            else {
                $('#alert').html(''); $('#alert').css("display", "block"); $('#alert').addClass("field-validation-error");
                $('#alert').append('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong> Failure!Request not placed !!! </strong>');
            }
        }
    });
```

The Dev Console is saying this:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Googling results in timeout solution. I don't think there is a timeout involved here.
No?

Comment: At what line do you get this exception?

Comment: Code looks fine, that only guess I have is that something wrong with 'DisplayMessage' function

Comment: BTW, why do you need 'async: false'? Maybe this can somehow cause this error?

Comment: add the DisplayMessage code please....

Comment: @Ivan thank you for the guidance. It was the DisplayMessage which had the setTimeout call. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Codehelp, always welcome)

Comment: For me this error was causing due to `async: false`.

Comment: You (codehelp) or @Ivan should create an answer and accept it if that's what fixed it for you.